# Clear back stack when application object gets killed by the system

Tags: android, back-stack

I have an application with a lot of activities. Among them there is `InitialActivity` which loads the core data. It's a launcher activity and none of the next activities can live without the loaded data.

So I launch the app, the `InitialActivity` is loading data, then navigates to the `MainActivity` and then I'm browsing to some `FarAwayActivity`. Then I'm switching to other apps (some of them are heavy games) and my application is getting killed on the background. I've inserted log call in my `Application.onCreate()` and I can see that it's called again, when I switch back to my application. So I'm sure that the app is killed on the background. But Android brings the very last `FarAwayActivity` to top and it crashes immediately because all the loaded data are nulls.

So the question is: how can I tell the application to start over from the `InitialActivity` when (and only when) it's getting killed and restored? Something like "forget my back stack", but presumably automatically, in the manifest.

I've already read and tried everything from [Activity tag docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html), but nothing matches my expectations. The closest thing is `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"`, but it clears all other activities on the stack when relaunching app from desktop (and app isn't killed yet, so all the data are available). To be clear, I want to start with InitialActivity only after the app was actually killed.

Comment: did you find any callback on Application class when your application context is getting killed? As far as my best knowledge goes, there is none. if there were, then you could clear your full stack at that point. unless you don't have that specific callback point, you need to work around to decide about the data.

Comment: @AmitK.Saha : there are `Application.onLowMemory()` and `Application.onTrimMemory()` methods, but I doubt I can use them to clear the back stack. As I know back stack cleanup is performed by launching a single root `Activity` with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag. So launching new `Activity` at that point is definitely not OK.

Comment: Application.onTrimMemory() and Application.onLowMemory() are only special event callback , they are not always called. So we can't use them for this purpose.

Comment: I use the OnResume method where I check some elementary variables. Also keep a copy of pointers to Intents started. When the variables are cleared, I call the 'reset' option, which tries to shutdown all Intents and restarts the MainActivity. Not an ideal solution, so still looking for one, but until then, this cuts down on crashing.

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest you to instead of storing it in the Application, you could pass your data to your Activity through Intent.
This way when the Activity get restored, the saved Intent will bring its data back.

Now to a suggestion to your actual question:

1. When your Activity gets restored, you will check if your data in the Application object is null
2. if they are you should call this:

   ```
   Intent newIntent = new Intent(FarAwayActivity.this, InitialActivity.class);
   newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
   newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(newIntent);
   ```

Now it should clear the stack till find InitialActivity.